# A subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ equipped with euclidean topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have started learning topology. I came across the following question:

Let 
$S$ be the subset of  $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of all points 
$(x
,
y)$ of $[0, 1]\times[0, 1]$ for which $x$ or  $y$, or both, are irrational.

Which of the following are true ?

1. $S$ is connected.
2. $S$ is compact.
3. $S$  is totally disconnected.

Comment: Do you know what the definitions of connected, compact, and totally disconnected are?

Comment: Yes, I know the definitions. I have a feeling that $S$ is totally disconnected and not compact. Am I correct ?

Comment: Well, feelings are often wrong when it comes to math. What are the definitions you have for each of these terms?

Comment: Connected- A set is connected if it cannot be written as the disjoint union of two open sets.


Totally disconnected- A set is totally disconnected if the only connected subsets of the set are singletons.


Compact- A set is compact if every open cover admits a finite subcover.

Comment: Alright, so let's go about showing that $S$ is either connected or not connected. If $S$ is connected, then there are no open sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cup B = S$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. The best way to show this might be true is by using a proof by contradiction, i.e. let $A$ and $B$ satisfy these conditions, and show that this implies something that contradicts something we already know or have assumed.

Comment: About compactness, I have an idea. Correct me if I am wrong. A compact metric space is complete (and totally bounded). But $S$ is not complete, hence not compact.

Comment: We usually talk about completeness with regard to spaces, not necessarily sets. A compact set contains its limit points. Can we write down a limit point of $S$ that is not in $S$?

Comment: $S$ is not closed, hence not compact.

Comment: Right, so we should show that $S$ is not closed, which comes from $S$ not containing its limit points.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$S$ is connected:

Actually, it is path connected. Suppose$(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2) \in S$. If $x_1$ and $y_2$ are irrational, then the path $(x_1,y_1)\rightarrow (x_1,y_2) \rightarrow (x_2,y_2)$ is in $S$. If $x_1$ and $x_2 $ are irrational, then the path $(x_1,y_1)\rightarrow (x_1,\sqrt{2}/2) \rightarrow (x_2,\sqrt{2}/2)\rightarrow(x_2,y_2)$  is in $S$.

$S$ is not compact since $S$ does not contain all its limit points. For example $(\sqrt{2}/2^n,\sqrt{2}/2^n)$.

Comment: For compactness in terms of open covers, take the open cover given by $\{(x,y) \mid x + y  < 1 - \epsilon\}$, for $\epsilon \in \mathbb R_+$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For connectedness you may  find a (simple) path in $S$ connecting any two points in the set.

Comment: Be careful with this. Connected and path-connected are not the same thing; path-connectedness (what you've mentioned) implies connectedness, but you cannot use the nonexistence of a path between two points in the set to imply non-connectedness. See [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/topology/connnotpathconn.pdf) for counterexamples.

Comment: I am aware. In the present case it goes the right way...

Comment: In the present case it does; this was more of an annotation for the benefit of the asker.